# How to let search return elements from queries that are part of the word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, full-text-search

I'm using [the acts_as_index plugin](https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed/) for search and I've noticed that it seems to only return elements whose words match the exact query. I want to return elements even if the query is only part of a word. How would I configure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acts_as_indexed only supports partial word matches at the beginning of the word.  Here is an example from the docs:

> Terms that begin with ^ will match records that contain a word starting with the term. ’^cat’ will find matches containing ‘cat’, ‘catapult’, ‘caterpillar’ etc.

This is to be expected from an indexed search.  Searching for partial matches anywhere in a word would negate the benefits of using an index.

Comment: For the record, your last statement is only true for full-word indices. Indexing the original word's reversed form ("drow" for "word") gives you "ends-with" searching for similarly reversed queries, while indexing partial forms ("word", "ord", "rd") gives you "contains". Building indices like this trades index size for query flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking this up, since acts as indexed accepts methods as fields, you could write methods which return all partial words for a field as a string